# Getting command line output dynamically

Tags: c#, command-line

I'm running a program using command line in c# this program produce some logs while its running in need to display this logs whenever it get change. I wrote the following code but it  shows all the logs once the process has been killed and during the running time my program is not responding. how can I fix it?

regards

```
ProcessStartInfo procStartInfo = new System.Diagnostics.ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "C:\\server.py");
Process proc = new Process();
procStartInfo.WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden;
procStartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
procStartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
//procStartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
proc.StartInfo = procStartInfo;
proc.Start();
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
proc.WaitForExit(300);
LogstextBox.Text = output;
```

**Edited:**
well, I tried to use `OutputDataReceived` but it doesn't show any result, here is the changed code:

```
{
            //processCaller.FileName = @"ping";
            //processCaller.Arguments = "4.2.2.4 -t"; this is working
            processCaller.FileName = @"cmd.exe";
            processCaller.Arguments = "/c c:\\server.py"; //this is not working
            processCaller.StdErrReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
            processCaller.StdOutReceived += new DataReceivedHandler(writeStreamInfo);
            processCaller.Completed += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCanceled);
            processCaller.Cancelled += new EventHandler(processCompletedOrCanceled);
            this.richTextBox1.Text = "Server Started.." + Environment.NewLine;
            processCaller.Start();
    }

    private void writeStreamInfo(object sender, DataReceivedEventArgs e)
    {
        this.richTextBox1.AppendText(e.Text + Environment.NewLine);
    }
```

Comment: Please upvote/accept the answers that you find helpful. This is the way to give credit to those who have helped you out the most.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

This is the problem:

```
string output = proc.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
```

You won't get to the "end" of standard output until the process has terminated.

You should be reading a line at a time - or possibly just subscribing to the [`OutputDataReceived`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.outputdatareceived.aspx) event (and following the documented other requirements for that event).

EDIT: Here's sample code which works for me:

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;
using System.Threading;

class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        ProcessStartInfo startInfo = new ProcessStartInfo("cmd", "/c " + "type Test.cs")
        {
            WindowStyle = ProcessWindowStyle.Hidden,
            UseShellExecute = false,
            RedirectStandardOutput = true,
            CreateNoWindow = true
        };

        Process process = Process.Start(startInfo);
        process.OutputDataReceived += (sender, e) => Console.WriteLine(e.Data);
        process.BeginOutputReadLine();
        process.WaitForExit();
        // We may not have received all the events yet!
        Thread.Sleep(5000);
    }
}
```

Note that in your sample code, you're accessing the UI on whatever thread the `OutputDataReceived` handler is called - that looks like a bad idea to me.

Comment: You beat me to it. No surprise.

Comment: Thanks, I tried to use OutputDataReceived but couldn't figure out what I'm doing wrong, since its not working.

Comment: @Th3_c0d3r: Well, did you follow the instructions in the document? In particular, did you call `BeginOutputReadLine`?

Comment: @Th3_c0d3r: I've just edited my answer to include some code which works for me...

Comment: thank mate, now its working but not in my scenario! when I use `processCaller.FileName = @"ping";processCaller.Arguments = "4.2.2.4 -t";` its working like charm but when I change it to `processCaller.FileName = @"cmd.exe";processCaller.Arguments = "/c C:\\server.py";` it doesn't work. `server.py` runs from command prompt without any problem.

Comment: @Th3_c0d3r: Are you sure it's writing to standard output rather than standard error? It's hard to diagnose an issue that I can't easily reproduce...

Comment: I handle both standard output and error event. I'll edit my first post and put the new code FYI

Comment: @JonSkeet: You need to call `process.BeginOutputReadLine();` **after** starting the process and not before, otherwise you will get a run-time error. So your coded should be like this: `process.Start(); process.BeginOutputReadLine();`

Comment: @LiranFriedman: Um, I do... I'm not sure what's inpsired this comment...

Comment: @JonSkeet: By the way, `e.Data` only gives me the command I sent. Do you happen to know how to get the result output of that command ?

Comment: @LiranFriedman: My code above that *does* call `process.BeginOutputReadLine()` after `Process.Start()`? (I've just seen the extra `process.Start()` call, which I'll remove - but the code does already work.)

Comment: @LiranFriedman: As for the `e.Data` part - it sounds like you should ask a new question about that.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the [Process.BeginOutputReadLine Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.diagnostics.process.beginoutputreadline.aspx). The link shows a complete working example in C# which uses the `OutputDataReceived event`. That code example should do what you want.